# JQuery pass extra param to Ui Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm searching for a solution for my propblem.

I'm using MVC Razor for create a website.

In a list of products I would like to open a popup (Jquery dialog) in wich a partial view can be opened.

But   I can't get it to work.

This is what i have:

```
<table style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10"  >
    <tr>
        <th>Acties</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>omschrijving</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Afbeeldingen</th>

    </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)       
        {
            Product P1 = item.Product_1;
            Product P2 = item.Product_2;

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionImage("AddMedia", "Upload", new { id = P1.ProductId }, "../Site_images/New Document.png", 20, 20, "Afbeelding toevoegen")
                @Html.ActionImage("Details", "Products", new { id = P1.ProductId }, "../Site_images/Get Info Blue Button.png", 20, 20, "Details")
                @Html.Image("Site_images/Appointment Cool.png", 20, 20, "Reserveren")
                <button value='@P1.ProductId' id="opener">open the dialog</button>
            </td>
            <td>@P1.ProductCode</td>
            <td>@P1.Description</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@P1.Media.Count()</td>

        </tr>

            if (P2 != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>@P2.ProductCode </td>
                    <td>@P2.Description</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@P2.Media.Count()</td>

                </tr>
            }




        }
</table>
```

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var TheValue;


$(function () {

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Details',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load('@Url.Action("AddMedia", "Upload", new { id = " + TheValue + "})');
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#opener').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        TheValue = $(this).attr("value");
    });
});
```

As you can see I've passed the Product Id to each button (as a value)
Now, What I want to do is, when you click on the butten the value of the button is passed to the Dialog open event, so the partioal view will show the data of the selected product.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Where is your "Rendering partial view"? You only create Action,, It's not a using partial view.

Comment: That's where is the problem ... I don't know how to make it work an what to use ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved it,
Simply by passing a variable to a JScript function:

```
@{
     var HostHeader = Request.Headers["host"];
     var url = "http://" + HostHeader + Url.Content("~/Upload/AddMedia/");
 } 

    <div id="dialog" style="display: none" title="Dialog Title"></div>

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:ShowDialog('@P1.ProductId')">Show Dialog</a>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            function ShowDialog(id)
            {

                $('#dialog').dialog({
                   position: 'top',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 500,
                    height:500,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: 'Upload image',
                    modal: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).load('@url' +id);
                    },
                    buttons: {
                        "Close": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                })


        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be just:

```
$('#opener').click(function () {
        TheValue = this.value;
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');        
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I've noticed this was in the wrong order, 
But the real problem is how to make this code working:
$(this).load('@Url.Action("AddMedia", "Upload", new { id = " + TheValue + "})');

How to use the @UrlAction and then add the variable TheValue.

I also tried to make the url "fixed like this:

$(this).load('http://localhost:57604/TufTuf/Upload/AddMedia/' + TheValue);

But nothing happens ..